# log file not getting generated using log4j.xml in a web application

Tags: java, servlets, logging, log4j

Log file is not getting generated on the server. 
The server shows :

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger.
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

I am using log4j.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} |[%t]| %p | %c{1} | %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file"
        class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="../logs/logFile.log"/>
        <param name="append" value="true"/>     
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="32MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} |[%t]| %p | %c{1} | %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <priority value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>  
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

This is my servlet initialization for log4j :

```
public class Log4jInitializer
   implements ServletContextListener
 {
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0)
   {}

   /** Initialize log4j context */
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
   {
     ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
     String log4jFile = context.getInitParameter("log4jFilePath");
     String fullPath = context.getRealPath("/") + log4jFile;
     PropertyConfigurator.configure(fullPath);

     Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Log4jInitializer.class.getName());
     logger.debug("Log4J initialized successfully");
   }
 }
```

My web.xml is as follows :

```
<context-param>
        <description>log4J initializer</description>
        <param-name>log4jFilePath</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.util.Log4jInitializer</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Log file is not getting generated on the server. I am using tomcat 6 to deploy my application.

Can anyone help?

Comment: At times, you must be looking at wrong path

Comment: The file is there. It is picking up the file else would have shown FileNotFoundException. Also, I added a condition to check whether file exists or not, it displayed true.

Comment: Not sure why your code isn't working. But, is there a reason that you're doing it this way in particular? Why don't you either: a) specify a "log4jConfiguration" context parameter that points to your file, or b) just name your file log4j2.xml and keep it in WEB-INF (and log4j will find it there)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config is XML but you use `PropertyConfigurator`. Try `DOMConfigurator`.

Comment: Thanks .... It worked !! Log file is getting created and logging is proper. thanks a lot !!